# => sign is showing in juniper srx100

Tags: juniper, juniper-srx

After booting the device, 
"=>" sign is showing in Juniper SRX 100 router
please support.
We are trying hard to restore the OS, but still failed, kindly support us urgently.

Comment: This means that the device is in U-boot mode. what happens when you type in 'boot'?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Please review this article, hopefully it will help you:

[Installing JUNOS Software](http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/software/junos-security/junos-security10.2/junos-security-admin-guide/section-srx-series-tftp-loader.html)

From u-boot:

```
=> setenv ipaddr 10.157.70.170
=> setenv netmask 255.255.255.0
=> setenv gatewayip 10.157.64.1
=> setenv serverip 10.157.60.1
=> saveenv
```

Reboot into the loader:

```
Loader>install tftp://10.77.25.12/junos-srxsme-10.0R2-domestic.tgz
```

(Of course, use network settings relevant to your environment, and an image filename that you posses.)